# Specialized frame warranty - cracked Alu seat tube

Tags: frames

I have a Specialized Allez Sport 2012. Which I purchased, new, just under 6 years ago in the UK. The aluminium frame has developed a crack in the seat tube, just above the brazed on derailleur mount. [image: See pictures.]

I note the newer models of this bike have reverted to a band on front mech mount. Is this because cracks like mine are common, possibly caused by a recognized design flaw?

Whilst I understand aluminium frames have a fatigue problem it isn't the type of crack I would expect to see. The bike has done just under 10,000 miles.

Am I likely to get a replacement frame under the lifetime frame warranty. If so how long is it likely to take?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because our opinion on whether Specialized's warranty covers this is basically irrelevant. Only Specialized can tell you if they'll warranty this.

Comment: I believe the question is pertinent as I'm asking if people regard this type of crack as due to an inherent flaw in the frame. I understand bike manufacturers are liable to reject claims which they suspect are due to collision damage, cracks such as one under the down tube where it meets the head tube. It is also valuable to know how long these types of issue take to be resolved.

Comment: OK but still, what do you have to lose by just asking Specialized? Even if we were to say that Specialized wouldn't warranty it, you'd be silly not to ask them on the advice of random strangers on the internet. And if Specialized refuse, the views of random people on the internet are unlikely to sway them. I'd have no objection in principle to a question of "How long does Specialized take to do warranty replacements?" though I suspect that would just end up as an opinion poll. Bob: "I got a new frame in two weeks" Jim: "Wow, you're lucky -- I'm still waiting six months later", etc.

Comment: I had already asked my dealer to contact Specialized. However I don't want to go without riding for an extended period so I'm dithering whether to buy a new bike to cover me until the Specialized is replaced. The choice of which interim bike I will buy is also determined by if Specialized are going to replace my frame. or not. I would also have thought types of crack / frame warranties would be of general interest.

Comment: Is there really much scope for general interest? Even for other people with Specialized bikes, the answer is going to depend entirely on the specifics of the situation. Anyway, I'm not going to bang on about it any more. I've voted to close but nothing will actually happen unless four other people agree with me, and only one has so far.

Comment: Many/Most major manufacturers offer lifetime warranties on frames. I did not intend to limit discussion to Specialized, I only quoted my specific bike model because of the design change related to where my bike cracked. I didn't put Specialized in the title, someone else made that edit. I was interested in the general validity of lifetime warranties. I can't see why this isn't of interest to all bike owners who wish to buy a new bike and ride it a significant distance. Particularly as some reports in forums suggest modern lightweight frames do have very limited life spans.

Comment: This isn’t a discussion forum: it’s a question and answer site. Different manufacturers will have different policies so I doubt that all manufacturers can be covered by one question. For more information on how the site works, please see the [tour] and the [help].

Comment: Adding for clarity - **that bike is unsafe to ride** so don't ride it at all.   Do dig out your paperwork from the initial purchase.

Comment: And do come back after its all over, to add your own answer on how things went for you.  Closure is always appreciated, even though its going to be biased by your location, and EU requirements (6 years ago is pre-brexit.)

Comment: @Criggie _Today_ is pre-Brexit.

Comment: @DavidRicherby yes I meant that in the future, the EU minimums won't necessarily apply in the UK.  But because this bike was bought before Brexit then the minimums of the day apply.  For a decent bike brand like this the term will be much longer than the minimum anytime.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [current Specialized warranty policy](https://media.specialized.com/support/0000009968/0000009968_r3.pdf) I'd say you are covered.

Only one way to find out for sure though - contact Specialized and ask to make a warranty claim. You will find out if they will cover it soon enough.

Unless someone here has been through the same process recently it's hard to say how long it would take.